# How to manage automatically generated c-files from matlab coder?

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2015, matlab-coder

I have an existing dll with multiple functions, let's call it `mylib`. I decided to use matlab coder to help me write my c-files. These c-files are compiled and linked to generate `mylib` using VS 2015.

So I test this theory i first started by converting `funcA.m` to `funcA.c` using `matlab coder ver 3.4 (R2017b)` . `funcA` is ust a simple mathematical function. Then I compiled and linked all the c-files generated by matlab coder to include `funcA` inside `mylib`. And this worked perfectly. Meaning, `funcA` which was originally a m-file was compiled, linked to `mylib` and had produced the accurate results.

The problem arises when I use matlab coder to generate my second function. Let's call the second function -> `funcB`

After converting funcA.m to funcA.c, matlab coder had generated other c-files which includes `xgeqp3.c` and `xnmr2.c` and its corresponding header files. I consider them non-readable by humans because they were automatically generated by `matlab coder` and it is not human friendly to read them as you can tell by the name of the c-files. However, they are being called by `funcA` so they have to be compiled into the library as well.

These matlab generated c-file caused me problems because when I converted `funcB.m` to `funcB.c`, it had also generated `xgeqp3.c` and `xnmr2.c`. Although the files names are identical, its contents are different, with different formal parameters and of course different c-codes, even though they have the same function name and file name.

So the same library cannot contain these two functions generated by matlab coder because the declarations for `xgeqp3.c` and `xnmr2.c` contradicts. I'm sure other people might have the same problem. Is there a way I can manually name the extra c-files generated my matlab coder so that I can avoid such duplicate names? Or is there a way I can manage the c-files with duplicate names but different codes? The easier option is to create separate libraries for the two functions. But I want all my mathematical functions to be in the same library.

How should I handle this situation? I'm open to new ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Matlab doesn't give you any way to control the names of the output files? What about the output directory?

Comment: nope, even if I rename the output files, I still have to rename the function names as well, including all the times the duplicate function is being called. At the moment, I separated the intermediate directories for my obj file but at the end of the day there's still two duplicate function names being compiled into the same library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate the c code together for all the functions that you want compile in the same dll.
If you are using command-line you should do:

```
codegen funcA, funcB
```

If you are using the Matlab Coder App, add both functions as entry point files.

Comment: seems like this is the only way. By any chance do you know how to auto define unbounded array inputs?  Auto define would be useful when other people want to make additions to my project. For example, a second person wants to add `funcC` but has to be able to reproduce the same initial `funcA` and `funcB`. Now, i'm having trouble in autodefining unbounded array inputs